# How can I add custom type to NextApiRequest in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, next.js, middleware

I have a middleware that checks whether the user making the request has a valid JWT token for requests to the APIs in Next.js. I wrote this middleware using TypeScript, but I get a type error.

My code is below:

```
import { verifyJwtToken } from "../utils/verifyJwtToken.js";
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import cookie from "cookie"

const authMiddleware = (handler: NextApiHandler) => async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  try {
    
 
    const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || '')
    const token = cookies.token
    const verifiedToken = await verifyJwtToken(token)

    if (!verifiedToken) {
      throw new Error('You have no access to do it.')
    }
    
    const userId = Number(verifiedToken.id)

    // Call the API route handler with the updated request object
    return handler({ ...req, userId }, res)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'You have no access to do it.' })
  }
}

export default authMiddleware;
```

The error is below:

```
Argument of type '{ userId: number; query: Partial<{ [key: string]: string | string[]; }>; cookies: Partial<{ [key: string]: string; }>; body: any; env: Env; preview?: boolean | undefined; ... 35 more ...; eventNames(): (string | symbol)[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextApiRequest'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userId' does not exist in type 'NextApiRequest'.ts(2345)
```

To fix this error, I created a custom interface that extends `NextApiRequest` and includes the `userId` property. Here's an example:

```
import { NextApiRequest } from 'next'

interface CustomNextApiRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  userId: number
}

export default CustomNextApiRequest;
```

Then, I tried to use this custom interface as the type for your `req` parameter in the middleware function, like this:

```
import CustomNextApiRequest from './CustomNextApiRequest';

const authMiddleware = (handler: NextApiHandler) => async (req: CustomNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  // ...
}
```

But didn't work. Btw, **this code works**. But I want to fix this type error.

And by the way, here is an example of how I use the `authMiddleware`:

```
async function addCommentHandler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  // My code goes here...
}
export default authMiddleware(addCommentHandler);
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using this `authMiddleware`?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar of course

async function addCommentHandler( req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse, ) {
my code goes here...
}

export default authMiddleware(addCommentHandler);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `CustomNextApiRequest` declaration is correct. The issue is in how your middlewares are chained together. I would suggest you have a `CustomNextApiHandler`, as below (feel free to adapt the return type):

```typescript
interface CustomNextApiRequest extends NextApiRequest {
  userId: number;
}
export type CustomNextApiHandler = (req: CustomNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => void;
```

Your `addCommentHandler` would use the above `CustomNextApiHandler` type:

```typescript
export const addCommentHandler: CustomNextApiHandler = (req, res) => {};
```

And finally, your `authMiddleware` will be as follows (notice the new comment):

```typescript
const authMiddleware =
  (handler: CustomNextApiHandler) => async (req: CustomNextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    try {
      const cookies = cookie.parse(req.headers.cookie || "");
      const token = cookies.token;
      const verifiedToken = await verifyJwtToken(token);

      if (!verifiedToken) {
        throw new Error("You have no access to do it.");
      }
      const userId = Number(verifiedToken.id);
      // Added it like this instead of destructuring it
      req.userId = userId;
      // Call the API route handler with the updated request object
      return handler(req, res);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(401).json({ message: "You have no access to do it." });
    }
  };
```